# linux servers remote managment python fabric

Tags: linux, fabric

Can anyone give me examples for the following scenarios on python fabric? I have been searching for weeks but just can not seem to get the right formula going.

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. rsync a folder from local server to a remote server using a specific user and ssh keys
2. Start a installation remotely (java app etc) as that user

Comment: Maybe you should post what you tried unsuccessfully so someone can point you in the right direction.  And you should accept answers to your older questions if they helped you.

Comment: Did you consider accepting some of the answers to your questions? This will encourage people to answer any new questions.

Comment: my bad gentleman and yes you can laugh.. I didnt know how to accept answers.. NOW I do..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of what I was playing with:

```
def deploy():
  if os.path.exists('%s/media' % os.getcwd()):
    print(green("Install Media Found..."))
    print('rsync -vazC --force --delete --exclude-from=%s/rsync_exclude.txt -e "ssh -p%s" %s/ %s@%s:%s' % (os.getcwd(), env.port, os.getcwd(), env.user, env.host, deploy_to));
  else:
    print(red("Install Media Not Found!"))
    print('rsync -vazC --force --delete -e "ssh -p%s" %s/ %s@%s:%s' % (env.port, os.getcwd(), env.user, env.host, deploy_to));
```